# Querying AR with a list of possible values

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I would like to query a `Model` with `where` where certain combinations of columns occur from a list of possibilities

specifically, the model has a polymorphic association of `d_type` and `d_id`

with d_type could be `'Gal'` or `'Bar'`

so before, I would do some logic to get the possible ids for each class that I want to query the `Model` table for

is there a way to do this like

```
Model.where("d_type = 'Gal' AND d_id = :g OR d_type = 'Bar' AND d_id = :b", g: g_ids, b: b_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a nicer way to do it but here is something to play around with:

```
combined_conditions = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']].inject(nil){|mem,(v1,v2)|
  condition = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
    Foo.arel_table[:baz].eq(v1).and(Foo.arel_table[:bar].eq(v2))
  )
  mem = mem ? Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('OR', mem, condition) : condition
};

puts Foo.where(combined_conditions).to_sql
```

gives:

SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos"  WHERE (("foos"."baz" = 1 AND "foos"."bar" = 'a') OR ("foos"."baz" = 2 AND "foos"."bar" = 'b') OR ("foos"."baz" = 3 AND "foos"."bar" = 'c'))